# Message: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file - APNS

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I am using EasyAPNS PHP library for APNS. I am trying to send notification from localhost but APNS is not connecting and through the following error

```
Message: stream_socket_client(): Unable to set private key file `F:\xampp\htdocs\appBuilder\assets\pn_certificates\3433442831346007_pn_certificate_sandbox.pem'

Message: stream_socket_client(): failed to create an SSL handle

Message: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
```

Pleas any one know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This Issue will occur because of the certificate file mismatch, Check your provision profile while creating certificate or .pem file.